# Why is npm throwing the error "checksum failed while installing @angular/cli"?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I'm using node v6.11.5 and npm 3.10.10 and 64-bit OS, and while installing @angular/cli I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v6.11.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\Shubham\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-6192-9e
acb63c\registry.npmjs.org\rxjs\-\rxjs-5.5.2.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 28d403f0071121967f18ad665563255d54236ac3
npm ERR! Actual:   c2b697120c7dc0e6728da0e7636b90e15723cc24
npm ERR! From:     http://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs/-/rxjs-5.5.2.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log
```

I'm trying to solve this since last night, but each time this shasum check failed is all I'm getting. I tried the following things:

1. I configured the npm registry to both http and https. Didn't worked.
2. Checked the path OS path variables, and the directory where node is
   installed. Found nothing.
3. Tried to clean npm and uninstalling and installing angular/cli.
   Didn't worked.

Comment: Did you see this thread from 2012?: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2701 (#issuecomment-40927831 explained a registry workaround).

Comment: Is the checksum failing if you try to install any other modules?

Comment: I didn't try installing modules other than @angular/cli. I'll update you about this in a moment. And yes I did checked that issue, It doesn't solve my problem though.

Comment: @stealththeninja tried installing express but didn't worked.! any help yet ? If you need log file then I can provide you that as well.

Comment: It's Monday, still into the console waving error.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Local setup issues are tough to debug as there's a lot of trial and error, keeping a list of what you've tried and resulting outcomes.

This is an attempt at a list of suggestions. I suspect you've tried many of these, I hope this helps organize your efforts.

1. Verify npm [registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry): `npm get registry` (expect: https://registry.npmjs.org/)
2. Update npm to latest: `npm install npm@latest -g`
3. Remove `package-lock.json`
4. [Uninstall](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm) npm completely before [reinstalling](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node#installing-npm-manually), including npm and npm-cache directories: `sudo npm uninstall npm -g`
5. Uninstall node completely (including npm again) and reinstalling

Along the way, I did come across similar github issues:

- [integrity checksum failed when using sha1 - Node v8+](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13635#issuecomment-322967019) (see comment)

> Hi @Rogasch I will suggest you to completely uninstall node and npm.
>   Also delete npm and npm-cache folder. And reinstall using
>   node-v6.11.2-x86.msi installer.   3 ❤️ 1
>
> i had the same issue and npm install -g npm fixed it for me
>
> I got this problem when I got package-lock.json included in the
>   commit. After removing package-lock.json I could run npm install
>   without errors again.

- [npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17146) **(OPEN)**

Comment: still don't understand why we can have a `checksum` error when the registry is the same ? I don't understand why `npm install -g npm` solve the problem ?

Comment: Me neither. However, `npm install -g npm` did the trick for me!

Answer (score 7):

I deleted the file `package-lock.json` and re-ran `npm install`.

Comment: it's not a good solution if you want to use the exact versions specified in the `packakge-lock.json`

Comment: This answer resolved it for me. GIt never updated the package-lock. I thought this was a pipeline problem.

Comment: This answer pointed out to me the way npm was working with checksums. I am working on a local npm repo on which I have deleted a version package and replaced it by another package at same version (very bad practise by the way, but I judged it was relevant in my specific case).

I just replaced the sha512 values in the package-lock.json file instead of deleting the whole package-lock.json file

Answer (score 3):

it's a build problems on windows, try these steps:

```
npm install -g node-gyp

npm install --global windows-build-tools

npm install -g angular-cli
```

Comment: The same error is thrown while installing modules that you've recommended. Windows is not a problem. Please let me know if you have other solutions.

Comment: what does those packages mean anyway. e.g. node-gyp @FatehM.

Comment: it's a Node.js native addon build tool  https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Comment: ok try to clean "npm cache clean", may be you have a corrupt version , and then restart again

Comment: Angular-cli needs python

Answer (score 1):

On our **Ubuntu 18.04**, we just needed to do the following:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Answer (score 1):

Run powershell as an administrator and then run these commands.

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `npm` and `npm-cache` by going to `%AppData%` and retry it will work fine

Comment: No I tried but it's not the cause. It's somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the node and then install the latest version of angular cli

Answer (score -1):

For me, my registry address was having http instead of https. When I checked my registry address with,

```
npm check registry
```

I saw http://registry.npmjs.org/ . I changed my registry address with https version

```
npm config set https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

And all the problems went away.